# Modifying html dropdown to searchable dropdown using Chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a working dropdown which gets its value from MySQL database in PHP.

I want to have a searchable dropdown instead of scrolling the list by using Chosen plugin.

Now, my question is how should I change my regular dropdown into Chosen dropdown? 
(I need to know the procedure)

here is my code:

```
 <form> 
    <select name="mySubmit" onChange="drawChart(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select an option:</option>
 <?php


 // Make a MySQL Connection
 $con = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

 // Create a Query
 $sql_query = "SELECT `Name`, `id` 
            FROM info AS t1
            where
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                from info AS t2
                where t2.Name = t1.Name AND (t2.`Date`) > (t1.`Date`)) = 0";

 // Execute query
 $result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die($sql_query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<option value='. $row['id'] . '>'. $row['Name'] . '</option>';
 }
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
 </select>
 </form>
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you have to give a class or id to your select HTML element.

```html
<select class="chosen" .... //same html/php code
```

Then in your javascript code, you call the jQuery chosen plugin to change this select to a chosen element like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chosen').chosen();
})
```

and it should work, you don't have to change anything in you php code, just give a class or id to you your select element so you can get if with jQuery selector. I advice you to read the chosen documentation

Comment: Thank you :) what should I do to data-placeholder? I get my data from database, so I cannot include a blank option as the first element of my select list.

Comment: data-placeholder is not the default value, it's just the message that you show like you did "Select an option" for example...
If it helps you, make this answer as a solution